# Fourier expansions in function fields

Tags: nt.number-theory

Is there an analog of Fourier series in the function field setting based on the Carlitz exponential? I mean, something like:

Let $\Omega$ be the completion of an algebraic closure
 of $\mathbb F_q\left(\left(\frac1T\right)\right)$ and $\exp_{\mathcal C}(z)=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{z^{q^n}}{D_n}$ be the Carlitz exponential on $\Omega$ where $$D_n=\prod_{\substack{a\in\mathbb F_q[T]\\ \deg a= n\\ a\text{ monic}}}a.$$
One denotes by $\xi\in\Omega$ the smallest (relatively to degree) period of $\exp_{\mathcal C}$. Let $f$ be an entire function on $\Omega$ such that $f(z+a)=f(z)$ for all $z\in\Omega$ and $a\in\mathbb F_q[T]$. Can we expand $f$ as
$$f(z)=\sum_{a\in\mathbb F_q[T]}b_a\exp_{\mathcal C}(\xi a z),\text{ where }b_a\in\Omega.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is and is called $t$-expansion rather than $q$-expansion - may be, though, you might want to replace your $\Omega$ by
$$
\widehat{\bar{K_\infty}}\setminus K_\infty
$$
where I denote by $K_\infty$ your completion $\mathbb{F}_q\big(\big(\frac{1}{T}\big)\big)$. This is the content of the paper *On the coefficients of Drinfel'd modular forms* by E-U. Gekeler, Inventiones Math. 93 (1988).

Comment: Are there conditions for which f admits such an expansion?
ANd when there exists a Fourier expansions, is there a formula giving the coefficients $b_a$

Comment: Well, as in the "classical" case, you need some condition at the cusps if you want to insist that the expansion is "integral" rather than rational. Similarly, assuming your periodic function to be a modular form, you have a notion of eigenform for which the coefficients get related to Hecke eigenvalues. In Section 6. of the paper Gekeler describes also in some detail the coefficients of Eisenstein series, but I would advise you to have a direct look at his paper.

Comment: I thought more about a more general criteria.
For example, in the classical casse, any periodic entire function on $\mathbb C$ admits a Fourier expansion. Is this the case in the function field setting?

Comment: Well, yes, periodicity plus some convergence at cusps (to guarantee convergence at $0$ in the disk) is enough. But, _again_, I advise you to look at Gekeler's Inventiones paper (for this, Def. 5.6 might be what you want).